# what is the most important thing to my App to avoid apple rejection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

what is the **most important** thing to my App **to avoid** apple **rejection**?

Comment: This link may help you http://www.makayama.com/checklist.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips for a successful AppStore submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551/tips-for-a-successful-appstore-submission)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is to be sure that your app actually complies with all of the guidelines of [this document](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) that are strictly related to what you implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use private APIs - the most important rule. If you violate it - 100% your app would be rejected

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to check the apple's  app review guidelines. They will give you all the things you need to know in the best possible manner. Please read them once. This thing helped me a lot. 
[APP STORE REVIEW GUIDELINES](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)